# Mongoose one to many relationship issue

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user model and a car model. One user can have multiple cars. Here is the code -

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    age:String,
    cars:[{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Car"
    }]
})

const User = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema)

let CarSchema = new Schema({
    make:String,
    model:String,
    owner:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"User"
    }
})

const Car = mongoose.model("Car",CarSchema)
```

I am creating a user and a car model and storing the user id in the car and vice versa like this -

```
const user = new User({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name:'Raj',
    age:50
})

user.save(function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    const car1 = new Car({
        make:'Toyota',
        model:'568',
        owner:user._id
    })
    car1.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }) 
    user.cars.push(car1)
    user.save()
})
```

This works but if I need to perform an operation on one Car model,then it obviously wont reflect on the user car array and I have to do it separately i.e the models are not 'actually' linked. How can I make it so that performing an operation like delete on the Car model will automatically delete it from my user car array. Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way to delete cars from user when a car is removed.
So you need to make operation on both the documents.

But there is a simpler way with only parent referencing. Don't keep car references in the user model and use [virtual populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) to populate cars from user.

Here are the steps:

1-) Change your user schema to setup virtual populate:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    age: Number,
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

UserSchema.virtual("cars", {
  ref: "Car",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "owner",
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Note that I removed the cars field, added `toJSON: { virtuals: true }`  option in the schema, set up virtual. (also modified age type as Number).

2-) Now we can create a user and car like this:

```js
router.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({ name: "Raj", age: 50 });

  try {
    await user.save();

    const car1 = new Car({
      make: "Toyota",
      model: "568",
      owner: user._id,
    });

    await car1.save();

    res.send("User and car saved");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

As you see we needed 2 db operation instead of 3 since we don't need to push the car to the user's cars and save.

3-) Now we can populate the cars from user using populate:

```js
router.get("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).populate("cars");

    res.send(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

This will give output:

```
{
    "_id": "5ea685a3f1a0b02db8aaffe2",
    "name": "Raj",
    "age": 50,
    "__v": 0,
    "cars": [
        {
            "_id": "5ea685a5f1a0b02db8aaffe3",
            "make": "Toyota",
            "model": "568",
            "owner": "5ea685a3f1a0b02db8aaffe2",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "id": "5ea685a3f1a0b02db8aaffe2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just to be clear now I only need to perform operations on the cars array inside the user model to create/delete/update any cars in future and no other place right?

Comment: @SushmitChakraborty no, you just need to add, remove or delete cars in the cars collection. I guess the output in the answer confused you, the output is the result of population.